# SQL subset of queries beyond LIMIT of first results

Tags: mysql

With a MySQL query how do I get a subset of results from a database without getting everything and then sorting through them myself. For example if there are 1,000 results and I want to get results 100 to 110 how can I do that with SQL.

Here is a dumbed down copy of my query that gets the first 5 results where id equals 10. This is the query that will need to get a subset of all the results other than just the first 5.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 10 ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 10 ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 110, 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`LIMIT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) clause also supports an offset:

```
LIMIT offset, row_count
```

or

```
LIMIT row_count OFFSET offset
```